# How to pull a project from gitlab?

Tags: git, gitlab

How do i pull a project in gitlab?
Does pulling and cloning are the same functions?
Please tell me I am very new to git.

Answer (score 5):

> Does pulling and cloning are the same functions?

Pull and clone basically do the same thing of pulling code from the remote repository.

```
To download code for the first time along with the meta info about all
available branches we use clone`. Once the local clone is available,
we use pull to fetch the latest changes.
```

> How do i pull a project in gitlab?

You should supply the remote repository url(in http/ssh) to clone.

```
git clone https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2
```